# When I trigger UIAlertController from my custom cell, it presents but it isn't translucent. How can I fix this?

Tags: uitableview, uialertcontroller

I call this function from my custom cell delegate. It presents correctly bu it isn't translucent. So the larey behind my alert it probably isn't table view where cell is located. Help.

```
internal func menuBtnTapped(_ sender: myListTableViewCell) {

    let controller = UIAlertController(title: "File Transfer", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Move File", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.moveFileProtocol(sender)
    }))
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Copy File", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.copyFileProtocol(sender)
    }))
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Export File", style: .default, handler: { _ in self.exportFileProtocol(sender)
    }))
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was translucent actually, it just wasn't noticeable with amount of blur that it's applied by default.